# Python: Empty list boolean comparison

Tags: python, boolean

Hey all so I was reading through the documentation for Python and it states that any empty string, list, dictionaries, I think they are called objects I think?(I don't really understand the concept of objects :\ if someone would be able to explain it to me I would be happy). Anyways my question is `x = []; bool(x) # False` so therefore: shouldn't `bool(x==False)` be true? But it returns false and that's the part that I am confused about.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is an empty array.  If you convert an empty array to a boolean, you get `False`; but that doesn't mean that `x` is the same thing as `False`.